# Cannot access links and child pages in magnolia cms

Tags: java, freemarker, magnolia

So I want to access a link from a child of a child page(grandson? I don't know the name for it sorry). As the image shows

[Image of the pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwXhA.png)

I've tried with this code but that doesn't get me where I want. It goes to child, so just one level down.

```
[#assign subNavigationRootPage = navfn.ancestorPageAtLevel(content, 2)!]
    [#if subNavigationRootPage??]
       [#assign navItems = navfn.navItems(subNavigationRootPage)]
       [#list navItems as navItem]
          <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="${cmsfn.link(navItem)!}?id=${producto.id}" role="button">Ver detalles</a>
       [/#list]
    [/#if]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/service/local/repositories/magnolia.public.releases/archive/info/magnolia/templating/magnolia-templating-essentials-models/1.5.3/magnolia-templating-essentials-models-1.5.3-javadoc.jar/!/info/magnolia/templating/functions/NavigationTemplatingFunctions.html#ancestorPageAtLevel-info.magnolia.jcr.util.ContentMap-int-),

> depth == 1 would return the root page to this page, depth == 2 would
> return the child page of the root page, etc.

So maybe you want

```
[#assign subNavigationRootPage = navfn.ancestorPageAtLevel(content, 3)!]
```

instead of

```
[#assign subNavigationRootPage = navfn.ancestorPageAtLevel(content, 2)!]
```

I think it's confusing in any case.  The 'ancestor' of a node should travel up the tree, not down it.  Maybe it should rather be 'descendent'.

Comment: I'll try that Thank you. I know it should't go down, but that's the best way I could get it to  work, if you have any suggestion I'm more than welcome.

Comment: No I actually mean I think the API is confusing / poorly-named, not that you're using it incorrectly :)